# Django rest framework - http post calls create( ) method in the viewset twice resulting in serializer error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework to create the api endpoints. I overrode  the create function of CreateModelMixin class. When the front end send a POST request , **this create() is getting called twice at the same time like its being processed in parallel or something !!** - I can see all the log statements inside this create function printed twice . Hence when serializer save happens , only the first request object goes through and the second request object results in an error ( obviously , since it has been created already ).

My Viewset:

```
class AdGroupViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data_copy = request.data.copy()
    print 'the create request data'
    print request.data
    #Request data has params name appended with a'[]'
    #if its an array, hence removing '[]' from the name
    geo_key=''
    if 'geotargeting[]' in data_copy:
        geo_key ='geotargeting[]'
    elif 'geotargeting' in data_copy:
        geo_key='geotargeting'

    if geo_key:
        print 'geotargeting info present in incoming request'
        geos = data_copy.getlist(geo_key)
        del request.data[geo_key]
        print geos
        for geo in geos:            
            try:
                geoObj = GeoTargeting.objects.get(criteria_id=int(geo))
                print  'geo db id: '+str(geoObj.id)
                request.data.update({'geotargeting' : unicode(str(geoObj.id))})
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error in updating GeoTargeting "+str(e))
    try:

        for item in data_copy.getlist('iab_category[]'):
            request.data.update({'iab_category':unicode(item)})


        for item in data_copy.getlist('exchange[]'):
            request.data.update({'exchange':unicode(item)})

        for item in data_copy.getlist('creative[]'):
            request.data.update({'creative':unicode(item)})

        print "targeting iofo "+str(request.data[geo_key])
        print "iab info "+str(request.data['iab_category'])
        print 'exchange info '+str(request.data['exchange'])
        print 'creative info '+str(request.data['creative'])
        del request.data['iab_category[]']
        del request.data['exchange[]']
        del request.data['creative[]']


    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("error is "+str(e))
    try:

        print 'final data'
        print request.data
        serializer = AdGroupCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print 'serialzier is correct '
            serializer.save()
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            print serializer.data
            return Response(data=serializer.data['id'], status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)


        print "ERROR:"+str(serializer.errors)
        return Response(data=str(serializer.errors),status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('create error is '+str(e))
        traceback.print_exc()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Example of log statements printed twice :

```
the create request data

the create request data

 <QueryDict: {u'creative[]': [u'1785276'], u'cpm_target': [u'0'], u'tactic': [u'1'], u'end_date': [u'2016-03-25T00:00:00-07:00'], u'cpm_bid': [u'2'], u'geotargeting[]': [u'200532'], u'campaign_id': [u'6'], u'start_date': [u'2016-03-15T00:00:00-07:00'], u'ad_type': [u'0'], u'iab_category[]': [u'9'], u'exchange[]': [u'3'], u'bidding_freq': [u'0'], u'freq_cap': [u'2'], u'total_impression_limit': [u'2'], u'adgroup_name': [u'ram staging test4'], u'daily_impression_limit': [u'2']}>

<QueryDict: {u'creative[]': [u'1785276'], u'cpm_target': [u'0'], u'tactic': [u'1'], u'end_date': [u'2016-03-25T00:00:00-07:00'], u'cpm_bid': [u'2'], u'geotargeting[]': [u'200532'], u'campaign_id': [u'6'], u'start_date': [u'2016-03-15T00:00:00-07:00'], u'ad_type': [u'0'], u'iab_category[]': [u'9'], u'exchange[]': [u'3'], u'bidding_freq': [u'0'], u'freq_cap': [u'2'], u'total_impression_limit': [u'2'], u'adgroup_name': [u'ram staging test4'], u'daily_impression_limit': [u'2']}>

request method isPOST

request method isPOST

final data <QueryDict: {u'cpm_target': [u'0'], u'tactic': [u'1'], u'end_date': [u'2016-03-25T00:00:00-07:00'], u'cpm_bid': [u'2'], u'exchange': [u'3'], u'campaign_id': [u'6'], u'start_date': [u'2016-03-15T00:00:00-07:00'], u'ad_type': [u'0'], u'iab_category': [u'9'], u'geotargeting': [u'38824'], u'bidding_freq': [u'0'], u'freq_cap': [u'2'], u'total_impression_limit': [u'2'], u'creative': [u'1785276'], u'adgroup_name': [u'ram staging test4'], u'daily_impression_limit': [u'2']}>

final data <QueryDict: {u'cpm_target': [u'0'], u'tactic': [u'1'], u'end_date': [u'2016-03-25T00:00:00-07:00'], u'cpm_bid': [u'2'], u'exchange': [u'3'], u'campaign_id': [u'6'], u'start_date': [u'2016-03-15T00:00:00-07:00'], u'ad_type': [u'0'], u'iab_category': [u'9'], u'geotargeting': [u'38824'], u'bidding_freq': [u'0'], u'freq_cap': [u'2'], u'total_impression_limit': [u'2'], u'creative': [u'1785276'], u'adgroup_name': [u'ram staging test4'], u'daily_impression_limit': [u'2']}>

serialzier is correct
serialzier is correct
create error is
create error is
```

Versions:
    Django rest framework = 3.2.2
    Django = 1.6.5
    Apache = 2.2.29

The strange thing is that testing in local machine did not have this issue.
The request META is the same both the times.

Comment: It appears that you are not giving the full code for your `AdGroupViewSet`. Can you please add the complete code?

Comment: First of all. The code is to long :), too many print statement.

Comment: `create` method is not called twice. Reason of doubled log is .... logger. Check your `LOGGING` configuration in django `settings`. Somehow two logger definition are take to `log` statement and print it into console.

Comment: logger = logging.getLogger('stackoverflow')
And in `settings` add `'stackoverflow': {
                'handlers': [
                    'console'
                ],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': False
            },`

Comment: Yes , it does look like double logging . Thanks for that ! . I looked at the error logs and found something to do with whoosh and saving m2m relationships. Rebuilt the whoosh index and the problem went away !!